# How to disable or weaken recaptcha in firebase phone auth in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

everyone.
I am building react + firebase using firebase's phone authentication.
In desktop version, the captcha doesnt appear frequently but in mobile, it is so annoying.
How to disable or even weaken it?
The firebase phone authentication uses recaptch v3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can disable it on production. It can be done for testing environment though: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#integration-testing